# Adding new roles JHipster and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

I'm creating application using JHipster and MongoDb and I'm trying to add new roles.
I added new constants to security/AuthoritiesConstants but in my collection jhi_authorities I'm not seeing changes.

Is anybody knows how to add my new role to this collection?

Answer (score 0):

You must also add your new authorities to MongoDb, see `InitialSetupMigration.java`, either add them here or create a new migration.
See [doc](https://jhipster.github.io/using-mongodb/)

Comment: If I do that I will enforce that every deployment of my app has those authorities, I have a more dynamic scenario, so I would prefer a way in witch I can decide in a per deployment basis witch ones will be the Authorities, I think @Michał Styś is facing the same problem.

Comment: Ok then you can't use constants in java and you should implement your own role management or wait for this feature or contribute to it. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1995

Comment: It's not because you intialize your authorities in code (InitialSetupMigration) that every deployment of your app has those authorities. Your code can just  read them as properties from an external  application.yml

Answer (score 0):

Create new @ChangeLg and write method with @ChangeSet 
Like this example

```
@ChangeLog(order = "002")
public class AddOthersAuthorities {

 @ChangeSet(order = "01", author = "initiator", id = "03-addOthersAuthorities")
    public void addAuthorities(DB db) {
        DBCollection authorityCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_authority");
        // Role for super administration
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
                .get());
       // Role for company administration
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN")
                .get());
        // Role for branch administration
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_BRANCH_ADMIN")
                .get());
        // Role for employee
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
                .get());
        // Role for registred customer
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_CUSTOMER")
                .get());
        // Role for non registred customer
        authorityCollection.insert(
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_GUEST")
                .get());
    }

}
```

Comment: where should I create this file ?